How share splunk detected threats with ELK?
Is it possible to share detected threat by Splunk (even by ES) with other apps like ELK? I mean automatically share all events related to detected threats by Splunk and send them to ELK. How it could be done? could someone please help me.
Actually I want to get feeds from Splunk Automatically and process it in ELK.
